# Calling IronPython usercontrol method from ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls, ironpython

Im trying to call a method from an ascx user control in IronPython code from a C# aspx asp.net page. When I do a C# page to C# usercontrol method call I have no problem, the same when I do an IronPython page to IronPython usercontrol method call I have no problem either, but when I do a call from C# page to IronPython usercontrol method call I get a CS1061 error

The code Im using to call it, it's the same I use from C# to C# or IronPython to IronPython which would be (controlID).method() . The control regular properties are accessible (enabled, visible, etc) but the methods aren't. Any way to make this work?

Comment: Im not sure if the edited title is the best title, since if the asp.net page is coded in IronPython there is no problem (problem is when the asp.net page code is in C# and the usercontrol code in IronPython), but you are a most experienced user here, so I guess you know